# Parse.com -- Cloud Code/JS -- "Cannot call method 'set' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So, my Javascript isn't the best but I have to venture into it to run some Cloud Code functions. I have the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setCommentIsTitle", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query("Comment");
  query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);

  query.first({
      success: function(object) {

          object.set('isTitle', request.params.isTitle);
          return object.save();  },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

I logged the `objectId` I'm passing in as `request.params.objectId` and it's correct. What I don't get is that `success` is being called, but then I'm getting the following Cloud Code log when I `console.log` object:

```
I2013-10-21T17:27:52.120Z] object = undefined
```

And the following error returned in XCode:

```
code=141, error=TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

If I'm calling the `first` function on `query`, and `success` is being called, shouldn't that mean there is an object returned? Why is `object` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this was a stupid error on my part, but also abetted by a confusing Parse error message.

My class is called `Comments` and not `Comment`, so I was looking up the wrong class. However, since success was called on the query I started looking in all the wrong places for the error.

Why would success be called if I'm querying a class that doesn't even exist??